# $.cookie not returning all cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have cookies list like this

```
    key  value              domain          expiry                      HTTP
    usid 1234567            abc.domain.com  2014-12-01T23:54:12.256Z    yes
    ssid 1234534            abc.domain.com  2014-12-01T23:54:12.256Z    yes
    _ga  GA1.1.323232323    domain.com      2014-12-01T23:54:12.256Z    no
```

When I use **$.cookie** to get the cookies the output is

```
object
_ga: "GA1.1.323232323"
lang: "en"
```

also **document.cookie** returns the same result
How can I get all the cookies present

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are dealing with [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) cookies, which cannot be retrived through JavaScript. All accessible cookies should be returned by `document.cookie`.

If you have control over the server-side, then make sure that the `HttpOnly` option is not use for these if you want them to be accessible on the client.

> *It's also possible that the abc.domain.com cookies aren't returned
>   because that's not the same domain as domain.com - Pointy*

Comment: It's also possible that the `abc.domain.com` cookies aren't returned because that's not the same domain as `domain.com`.

Comment: @Pointy Are they really considered two seperate domains, even if one is a sub-domain of the other?

Comment: Well in general the same-origin policy treats the domain as a string in a "dumb" way, so I would not be surprised if that applied to cookies too.

Comment: yes the usid, ssid are httponly cookies, how can I clear those cookies

Comment: @hariszaman You want to clear them or read them on the client, it's not clear.

Comment: I want to read them and then clear them. but If reading is not possible I would like just to clear them

Answer (score 0):

The cookies that you are not seeing may be HttpOnly cookies. This means that they cannot been seen using Javascript.

You can see them using a network trace tool or most browsers dev tools will show them in the network trace.

Look for headers that have the HttpOnly attribute like this

```
Set-Cookie: <name>=<value>[; <Max-Age>=<age>][; expires=<date>][; domain=<domain_name>][; path=<some_path>][; secure][; HttpOnly]
```